# What is the adjectival form for "edit?"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, derivational-morphology

As in "that which could be edited," or "editable" if you will.

Comment: For what it’s worth, the Oxford Dictionary of English lists ‘editable’ as an adjective that can qualify text or software.

Comment: I couldn't find it listed as a recognized word at all, but thanks. And it sounds too much like "edible," which makes things worse :/

Comment: And first recorded in 1935.

Comment: @wanderer, welcome, you should use tools such as [onelook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=editable&ls=a) to search multiple dictionaries online.

Answer (score 12):

["editable" seems to be in-use currently](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=editable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) and is growing in popularity. Since it seems to be a relatively recent coining, I'd recommend using it for technical audiences but might avoid using it if I thought my audience would prefer more "established" words.

[image: ngram showing sharp rise in use of editable around 1980]

Also, the [Corpus of Contemporary American English shows some usage of the word](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=12872466) in the way you'd expect. Most of these uses are computer-related or academic publications.

Comment: So... what word/phrase did people use *before* the 1980's? ;)

Comment: I think before the rise of computers, "editing" was limited to, well, editors, and there wasn't any special need for a special adjective to describe that which could be edited.  Paper was inherently editable.

Comment: I just tried that google word-count-in-books-thing, and found that "revisable" *was* in heavier usage until the mid-1990's: 
http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=editable%2Crevisable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: *Editable* seems like a normal word that can be applied to text. But if OP is worried he might confuse it with *edible*, and thus be forced to [eat his words](http://thesaurus.com/browse/eat+ones+words?qsrc=2446&o=102334), he could consider [amendable](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&newwindow=1&q=amendable&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=qEO9Tv-2EM2T8gPu1ImvBA&ved=0CB0QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=b82765d88c56fc8f&biw=1138&bih=846)

Answer (score 8):

You could use [*revisable*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/revisability) if you don't like *editable*.

Answer (score 7):

Though I like editable best, *changeable* is a possible answer.

Answer (score 7):

How about "updateable", "changeable", and/or "modifiable" ?

Answer (score 5):

How about "mutable"?

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mutable

Comment: I just don't think "mutable" is apt for usage referring to text. It just doesn't sound right :/

Comment: Well certainly it depends on your specific application of the word. If you're writing for a technical audience I think that mutable would be a very concise choice. If you're writing for a non-technical audience "editable", as Bavarious suggested, might be the best fit.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, "editable" is technically correct.  Depending on the context, you may be able to say it in a different way, to avoid the awkward-sounding "editable":

Instead of:

> The box is light gray when the text is editable.

Consider:

> The box is light gray when you can edit the text.
>
> You can edit the text when the box is light gray.
>
> The box is light gray when editing is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Proper terms:

- Editable *
- Customizable
- Changeable *
- Alterable
- Modifiable *
- Revisable *

Slang:

- Modable

*Words stated in previous posts are marked with an astrix* *